# Comparing Negative result of correlation to ppscore

Tags: python, data-science, correlation

I have a simple question regarding ppscore. When I was calculating the correlation between two datasets(Columns) the result was was -0.248, which means when one when data increases the other will decreases but when I calculated the ppscore of the same columns the result was 0.37 from x to y and 0 from y to x. It clearly indicates that x can predicts y with 0.37 ppscore and y cannot predict x.

But what I actually want to know is the relation between 2 datasets, either it is directly proportional (positive) or inversely proportional(negative) with each other.

ppscore: https://github.com/8080labs/ppscore

Thank you,

Comment: Is this a programming question? Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: @AMC it's a data science question related to ppscore.
https://github.com/8080labs/ppscore

Comment: You might find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) discussion on ML-related Stack Exchange sites useful.

Comment: @AMC alright thanks.